# Why does cos(2^27) fail?

Tags: excel

It seems excel knows how to calculate `=cos(2^27-1)` but fails to calculate `=cos(2^27)`. That returns `#NUM!`. Does anyone know why?

Comment: Dunno. That number should be representable by even a single-precision float. But if you need the answer it's 0.645922217.

Comment: @MaxE.: hehe, thanks, I don't really need to calculate the value, I am just surprised by the very low limit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have no idea what sort of arithmetic that Excel uses internally, but at some point, with a large number, the error after you do a `mod 2*pi` operation is too substantial to produce a reliable answer.  Presumably they picked 2^27 as their cutoff.

[image]

Comment: they are possibly guarding against the prospect of a spreadsheet running on a 32 bits (single precision float) machine.

Comment: @Hot Licks: interesting point, I didn't think about the precision going down as the number becomes greater.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg - IEEE single precision has only 23 bits of precision, so it would run out of steam around 2^16., give or take.  It may be internally they're carrying 32 bits + exponent, and at 2^27 they'd be down to 5 bits.  (Keep in mind that often trig functions are implemented with a different number system than what's exposed.)

Answer (score 1):

This is behavior is not well [documented](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/sin-function-HA001228907.aspx?CTT=1).  The Sin Function documentation indicates that the argument is a Double, and the specified limits in the documentation indicate that the double type is stored as a 64-bit number ranging from 4.94E-324 to 1.797E308 (for positive numbers).

I suspect that it is not coincidental that 2^27 (134,217,728) bytes is *precisely* 128 megabytes, and it seems likely that there is an internal limitation for some trig functions (eg. COS, SIN and TAN, but interestingly, NOT for TANH, etc.).  This is not to say that this amount of memory consumption would be required - it's just that a programmer's implementation could have some (potentially unnecessary) limits on these types of inputs internally.

To get around this silly limit, simply use the following:

```
=COS(MOD(2^27, 2*PI()))
```

This works because the limitation does not exist for other operations, and is nowhere to be seen in the [Excel Specifications and Limits](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/excel-specifications-and-limits-HP010342495.aspx). :-)

It would be good for the documentation as linked provided a description of these limits, but unfortunately, it does not.

Comment: I don't think the **angle**, in radians, that is passed as an argument to a trig function has **anything** to do with memory size.

Comment: Sure.  I don't think that that amount of memory is necessarily being used, either.  The point is, the internal implementation could have some type of limit on the input for some (maybe unnecessary) reason, but it's just not documented well.

Comment: There is no possible way for that amount of memory to be used. Why would it? Calculating the cosine of a real number does not require a linear amount of memory in the size of the input. I agree with you that there is a (seemingly arbitrary) limit, I was simply disputing that this limit is in any way related to 128 megabytes.

Comment: I think we are in agreement that that amount of memory is not being used.  But the amount of memory being used, and a programmer's choice of defensive programming are different things.  There could be an internal limit that was put in place, which is unnecessary.

Comment: The reason I referenced 128 MB in the answer was because, to a programmer, 128 could seem like a "nice" round number to use for a limit.  It is not as arbitrary as other numbers.

Comment: Been programming for 40 years, and 128MB doesn't seem particularly "nice" to me.  Nothing at all special about that value.

Comment: And `mod(2^27,2*pi())` fails too.

Comment: @Hot Licks: Any power of two could be considered "nice" in my book.  And mod(2^27, 2*PI()) does work - I tried it out before writing about it.

Comment: And also, this is pretty off topic considering it misses the point of my posted answer, picking out a single sentence which is not all that influential toward the main point.

Comment: @Kirby - But see my answer above -- mod(2^27,2*PI()) apparently squeaks under the wire, but mod(2^30, 2*PI()) fails.